# Finding the minimum and maximum length of columns in a CSV file using shell script

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sh, gawk

I have several CSV files with multiple columns, and I want to get the max length, min length of individual columns and diff (max -min) for each column in the same CSV file. Example:

File:

```
abc 1234 4
bcd 23644 534
c 3232 6
```

Expected output:

```
    abc 1234 4
    bcd 23644 534
    c 3232 6

Max Length 3 5 3
Min Length 1 4 1
Diff 2 1 2
```

The following script for computing the MAX column length is producing the expected output:

```
awk -F, '
  { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)l[i]=((x=length($i))>l[i]?x:l[i])}
  END {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "Column"i":",l[i]} '
```

but there is problem with MIN Length script:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        cur = length($i)
        if ( (min == 0) || (cur < min) ) {
            minlength = i
            min = cur
        }
    } ;
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $minlength}'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the second script, the use of BEGIN shows that you need to read up on what BEGIN does.  Also, you speak of CSV files, and the awk scripts use commas as separators, but your examples have no commas in them.  Since "CSV" is a highly ambiguous designation anyway, it might help if you clarified what you mean.  In particular, do any of the fields have embedded field separators?  If a value in a field in the CSV files looks like `"abc"` (that is, with outer quotation marks), should that be counted as having length 3 or 5?  What about the length of `""""`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the starting values for the min and max arrays based on the first line of the file:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) maxlen[i] = minlen[i] = length($i)}
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            len = length($i)
            if (len > maxlen[i]) maxlen[i] = len
            if (len < minlen[i]) minlen[i] = len
        }
    }
    END {
        printf "Max Length"
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf " %d", maxlen[i]
        print ""
        printf "Min Length"
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf " %d", minlen[i]
        print ""
        printf "Diff"
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf " %d", maxlen[i]-minlen[i]
        print ""
    }
' file
```

Comment: Never use `l` (the letter `el`) as a variable name as it looks far too much like `1` (the number `one`), indistinguishable in some fonts, and so obfuscates your script. For example, `maxl[i]=l` looks like you're setting `maxl[i]` to `1`. Maybe use `cur` to match `max` and `min`?